# Ruby -- ensuring local variable doesn't collide with method name

Tags: ruby, mixins

I'm trying to slim down my fat models by applying the Single Responsibility Principle. I'm culling out a lot of common code into mixins, which are then included into multiple classes. However, I'm running into this strange problem of local variables colliding with method names (or attr_accessors) of the class which includes the mixin. For example:

```
module MyAwesomeMixin
  def update_total
    my_total = self.pricing_items.reduce(0) {|sum, x| sum + x} # this borks if the "host class" has a method called my_total=
    total = my_total
  end
end
```

The code snippet above has complete unintended consequences if the "host class" has a method called `my_total=` How do I ensure that the `my_total` variable is completely inside the scope of `update_total` method and has absolutely nothing to do with the environment around it?

Comment: Exactly what "unintented consequences" happen and how do they manifest?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the collision. I have defined a class MyClass which includes MyAwesomeMixin and `def my_total=(val)`, then `MyClass.new.update_total` does not call my_total. Can you give a code snippet and execution showing the problem ?

Comment: Also `total = my_total` line is useless. It creates local var `total` which is never used.

Comment: Pro tip: providing small runnable problem-demonstrating code snippet will help a LOT. Some power users don't even bother answering if they can't copy/paste/run your code and see the problem immediately. Moreover, I find that simply trying to compose such snippet often makes me realize what the problem is (and thus eliminates need for asking). I can't count number of times this happened to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's something you don't show us. In this case the only "unintented consequence" is that method `my_total=` is not called, because local var `my_total` is created.

```
module MyAwesomeMixin
  def update_total
    my_total = 10 # !> assigned but unused variable - my_total
  end
end

class Foo
  include MyAwesomeMixin

  attr_accessor :my_total
end

f = Foo.new
f.my_total # => nil
f.update_total
f.my_total # => nil
```

If you intend to call the setter, call it on `self`.

```
module MyAwesomeMixin
  def update_total
    self.my_total = 10
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.my_total # => nil
f.update_total
f.my_total # => 10
```

Comment: I'm completely confused, in that case. How is it that `puts my_total` references the reader method, but `my_total=something` creates a local variable?

Comment: If `my_total` local var exists, it will be used. If it does not exist, ruby will search for this name in outer scopes.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever there is ambiguilty between local variable and method interpretations, it will always be interpreted as local variable.

However, a local variable will not be available beyond a method definition, so you do not need to worry about name crash in the "host class". You only need to worry about it within the method definition of your `update_total`. And since you are using a fixed amount of local variables in your definition, you should be able to know which ones to take care.

**1. Ambiguity between local variable and setter method**

If you have this:

```
variable_name =
```

then it will always be interpreted as local variable assignment. If you want to refer to the method `variable_name=`, then you need to disambiguate it from local variable by using an overt receiver and/or a pair of parentheses like any of the following:

```
self.variable_name = foo
variable_name=(foo)
self.variable_name=(foo)
```

**2. Ambiguity between local variable and getter method**

If you have:

```
variable_name
```

and there is no such local variable in the scope, then it will be interpreted as a method call. If there is such local variable in the scope, then it will be interpreted as a local variable. If you want to call the method under such condition, again, you need to disambiguate it from local variable by using an explicit receiver and/or a pair of parentheses like any of the following:

```
self.variable_name
variable_name()
self.variable_name()
```